# How can I highlight the last row of an HTML table generated using Perl?

Tags: html, perl, html-table

The code below breaks up the @stat_array into fours and then
prints out fields into an HTML table with the OCOMsg2 cell in red - 
again - just one cell of the emailed table.

The boss told me that he wants the WHOLE LINE with the OCOMsg2 
in red - so the array below, all the elements

```
"ibfarm102  - localtick", 'New York", "hibmis100 -  procHKHD2 - Hongkong", "OCOMsg2"
```

need to be red.

Is there a way to do this with out rewriting the whole block - I really like this block.

```
@stat_array = ("ibfarm102  - localtick", "Boston" , "hibmis100 -  procHKHD2 - Hongkong", "PidMonRsp", 
"eufarm102  - localtick", "London", "hibmis100 -  procHKHD2 - Hongkong" , "PidMonReq" , 
"ibfarm102  - localtick", "New York" , "hibmis100 -  procHKHD2 - Hongkong", "PidMonRsp", 
"ibfarm102  - localtick", 'New York", "hibmis100 -  procHKHD2 - Hongkong", "OCOMsg2"); 

my @stat_array_rows = @stat_array; 
 while (my @stat_array_rows = splice(@stat_array_rows, 0 , 4)) {
  print MAIL "<tr>\n";while (my @stat_array_rows = splice(@stat_array_rows, 0 , 4)) {
  print MAIL "<tr>\n";
  for my $stat_row(@stat_array_rows) {
     if ($stat_row =~ /OCCOMsg2/){
        print MAIL "<td><font color=red>$stat_row[0]</font></td>\n";
      }
     else {
        print  for my $stat_row(@stat_array_rows) {
            if ($stat_row =~/OCAlive2/){
            print MAIL "<td><font color=red>$stat_row[0]</font></td>\n";
     }
     else {
         print MAIL "<td>$stat_row</td>\n";
     }
  }
  print MAIL "</tr>\n";
}
```

these are the results of the block:

```
<tr>
<td>ibfarm102  - localtick </td>
<td> Boston</td>
<td> hibmis100 -  procHKHD2 - Hongkong </td>
<td>PidMonRsp</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>eufarm102  - localtick </td>
<td>London</td>
<td> hibmis100 -  procHKHD2 - Hongkong </td>
<td>PidMonReq</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>ibfarm102  - localtick </td>
<td>New York</td>
<td> hibmis100 -  procHKHD2 - Hongkong </td>
<td>PidMonRsp</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>ibfarm102  - localtick </td>
<td>New York</td>
<td> hibmis100 -  procHKHD2 - Hongkong </td>
<td><font color=red> OCOMsg2</font></td>
</tr>
```

I somehow want Perl to print everything i the OCOMsg2 block red, not just that cell.

Comment: >The code below breaks up the @stat_array into fours and then
>prints out fields in to an HTML table wih the OCOMsg2 cell in red - 
>again - just one cell of the emailed table.

>The boss told me that he wants the WHOLE LINE with the OCOMsg2 
>in red - so the array below, all the elements  - 
>"ibfarm102  - localtick", 'New York", "hibmis100 -  procHKHD2 - >Hongkong", "OCOMsg2"
>need to be red. 

>Is there a way to do this with out rewriting the whole block - I >really like this block(thanks ysth)..

Comment: Please  edit your question with that information

Comment: Looks more like an html question than perl.

Comment: having a very difficult time formatting the html table that is generated by this script. again only the last cell, containing the OCCOMsg is printed in red - i need each cell in that line to be printed in red, not just that cell

Comment: Is this code right? You seem to be opening the TR element twice.

Comment: In fact this code doesn't even compile. The first 'else' doesn't even have a matching 'if'. If you want help, then it's polite to at least give us compiling code to look at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have the data in @stat_array_rows (a rather badly named variable in my opinion as it only contains a single row at a time) you just need to check if any of the elements contains 'OCOMsg2' and set a flag which you can use within the rest of the code.

```
my $is_OCOMsg2 = grep { /OCOMsg2/ } @stat_array_rows;
```

Also. This is 2011. People don't use the FONT tag any more. You should use CSS for this.

Comment: you totally nailed it with grepping the OCOMsg out of the array - it worked great. yeah this is a perl scrip that generated a email sent with sendmail. so the font tag stays. thank you again.

Comment: @davorg- the code that i posted was incomplete and you somehow figureed out just what i needed - thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to guess what you are about to do - your code as posted cannot be even compiled (things like `else` after `for` loop are pretty much invalid in perl).

What about something like this:

```
@stat_array = (
    "ibfarm102  - localtick", "Boston",   "hibmis100 -  procHKHD2 - Hongkong", "PidMonRsp",
    "eufarm102  - localtick", "London",   "hibmis100 -  procHKHD2 - Hongkong", "PidMonReq",
    "ibfarm102  - localtick", "New York", "hibmis100 -  procHKHD2 - Hongkong", "PidMonRsp",
    "ibfarm102  - localtick", "New York", "hibmis100 -  procHKHD2 - Hongkong", "OCOMsg2",
);

my @stat_array_rows = @stat_array;
while (my @cols = splice(@stat_array_rows, 0, 4)) {
    my $color = $cols[3] eq "OCOMsg2";
    print "<tr>\n  ";
    print join "\n  ", map {
              "<td>"
            . ($color ? "<font color=red>" : "")
            . $_
            . ($color ? "</font>" : "") 
            . "</td>"
        } @cols;
    print "\n</tr>\n";
}
```

Probably better way to colorize would be use of CSS, though.

Comment: @brw - i am sorry that this could not compile  - i posted at one i the morning and was having trouble formatting the question. i did not include all the information. next time i will be more careful.

Answer (score 0):

You'd better off using a template. For this purpose, I would go with [HTML::Template](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/HTML%3a%3aTemplate). Coupled with [List::MoreUtils::natatime](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/List%3a%3aMoreUtils), you can solve the problem cleanly.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings; use strict;
use HTML::Template;
use List::MoreUtils qw( natatime );

my $tmpl = HTML::Template->new(
    scalarref => \ do {local $/; <DATA>}
);

my @stat_array = (
    "ibfarm102  - localtick", "Boston" , "hibmis100 -  procHKHD2 - Hongkong", "PidMonRsp",
    "eufarm102  - localtick", "London", "hibmis100 -  procHKHD2 - Hongkong" , "PidMonReq" ,
    "ibfarm102  - localtick", "New York" , "hibmis100 -  procHKHD2 - Hongkong", "PidMonRsp",
    "ibfarm102  - localtick", "New York", "hibmis100 -  procHKHD2 - Hongkong", "OCOMsg2"
);

my @rows;

my $it = natatime 4, @stat_array;
while (my @cells = $it->()) {
    push @rows, {
        CELLS => [map +{CELL => $_}, @cells],
        HIGHLIGHT => $cells[-1] eq 'OCOMsg2'
    };
}

$tmpl->param(ROWS => \@rows);

print $tmpl->output;


__DATA__
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>
<table>
<TMPL_LOOP ROWS>
<TMPL_IF HIGHLIGHT>
<tr style="color:red">
<TMPL_ELSE>
<tr>
</TMPL_IF>
<TMPL_LOOP CELLS>
<td><TMPL_VAR CELL></td>
</TMPL_LOOP>
</tr>
</TMPL_LOOP>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: they do  not have the List::MoreUtils::natatime, module compiled at work - looks cool though. thanks for you help.